# How to "adjust" a data set so that the total sum is equal to 1. (I thought I knew the correct term for this)

Tags: math, statistics, dataset, normalization

I apologize ahead of time for the crude way this question is worded. I was under the impression for the longest time that what I'm trying to do is called "Normalizing data" but after googling to try and find the method to do this, I seem to be mistaken so I'm not sure exactly what it's called that I'm trying to do (bear with me please).

I have a set of data like this:

```
0.17407
0.05013
0.08520
0.02892
0.02986
0.06286
0.04453
0.00425
0.20470
0.02267
0.01470
0.02460
0.01735
0.01069
0.02168
0.13912
0.02004
0.02018
0.07837
```

When you add them all you get `1.05392`.

I'd like to "adjust" the data set so that the relative values all remain the same but the sum is equal to 1. When I googled normalizing data sets, I found a formula like this:

```
(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
```

However, this simply "ranks" each data point as a certain percentage of the maximum value so that your max value in your data set is equal to 1 and the minimum, 0.

Extra: Could someone enlighten me what this is called if not normalizing data. Obviously I've been carrying around this ignorant belief for far too long.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your data to sum to 1 you normalize your data. You normalize by dividing by the sum of you series (`sum_i x_i`, where `x_i` are the elements of your data series).

The formula you mention is another possible rescaling, but as you observed it has a different effect. Note that in the first case you map `x -> c*x` (in your case: `x -> 1/1.05392*x`), while the second case rescales with `x -> c*x + offset`. Note also, that the later is not linear (unless `min(x) = 0`), that is `f(x+y) != f(x) + f(y)`.

If your whole confusion is about the naming of things, than I would not worry to much. After all there is only convention and common agreement, but no absolute truth/authority. And the terms are reused in different fields, cf. [Normalization on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization):

> Normalization or normalisation refers to a process that makes something more normal or regular

Comment: Maybe this is my further ignorance, but what is `c` in this context? Also, what exactly is `sum_i x_i`? Is that just the sum of the data series? When I simply modify the formula I wrote to replace the denominator with the sum of the series, the resulting series doesn't sum to `1` but `0.92336`.

Comment: If you want your data to sum to 1, you normalize by dividing by the sum of your series (1.05392). That is `1.17407 -> 1.17407/1.05392`, ...)

Comment: Thank you. This seems painfully obvious now.